How to create a micrometer gauge with multiple tags which gets changed dynamically in java?
I'm trying to create a custom metric using gauge builder and with dynamic multi value tags. I'm trying to create unique timeseries for each tag for the same custom metric. For a static single timeseries with two tags, written the code as shown below.
But how to create a gauge builder for dynamic multi value tags , since gauge builder is getting built in the constructor itself ?
My Code:
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Gauge;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class LogParser {
   
    private final Gauge gaugeQueryExecTime;
    private long  gaugeExecTime;

    public LogParser(MeterRegistry meterRegistry){
        gaugeQueryExecTime = Gauge.builder("query.timer.duration", this, LogParser::getGaugeQueryTime ).tags("client_id","161.71.81.101").tags("query","SELECT name,marks from student")
                .register(meterRegistry);
    }

    public void publish() {
        gaugeExecTime = 51;
        log.info("gaugeExecTime {} ", gaugeExecTime);
    }
    long getGaugeQueryTime(){ return gaugeExecTime; }

}
 


Just a couple point regarding your approach: 1. Beware of possible cardinality explosion. If you will be putting arbitrary queries into labels this might cause problems with performance on Prometheus. And if you have unlimited number if possible queries there, consider using logging solution like Loki instead. 2. Usually for this kind of "time taken" metrics histograms are used.

Can you please provide the sample code as I'm new to prometheus ?


How to create a micrometer gauge with multiple tags which gets changed dynamically in java?

Have you looked at MultiGauge in the docs? https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/concepts/gauges.html#_multi_gauge
MultiGauge statuses = MultiGauge.builder("statuses").register(registry);
[...]

// run this whenever you re-run your query
statuses.register(
    resultSet.stream()
        .map(result -> Row.of(Tags.of("status", result.getAsString("status")), result.getAsInt("count")))
        .collect(toList()),
    true // whether to overwrite the previous value or only record it once
);

Though, I think what you are doing is not what you are asking: query.timer.duration. If you want to measure duration, try to use a timer. Also, if you want to measure jdbc, I would use this instead, it has Micrometer and Spring Boot support: https://github.com/jdbc-observations/datasource-micrometer
