Can we intercept RequestLogger of Cassandra Java driver and push custom Micrometer metrics to Prometheus?
I'm trying to extract three required fields (duration,query,client_id) from RequestLogger of Cassandra Java Driver and push it to prometheus actuator endpoint.
So, I've created CustomRequestLogger class by overriding existing RequestLogger. I need to create a gauge builder in the constructor to create and push custom Micrometer metrics. So, did the same. But the new constructor is never getting called.
My CustomRequestLogger:
 public CustomRequestLogger(DriverContext context) {
        this(new RequestLogFormatter(context));
    } // This is getting called

    protected CustomRequestLogger(RequestLogFormatter formatter) {
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }// This is getting called

    public CustomRequestLogger(MeterRegistry meterRegistry){
        gaugeQueryExecTime = Gauge.builder("query.timer.duration", this, CustomRequestLogger::getGaugeQueryTime )
                .register(meterRegistry);
    } // This constructor is never getting called so custom metric is not getting pushed to prometheus endpoint

Can someone please help me out in calling the 3rd constructor as well  ?

@Erick Ramirez.. Can you please suggest me out regarding the same in cassandra java driver ?

Please do not post the same thing twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78411636/how-to-create-a-micrometer-gauge-with-multiple-tags-which-gets-changed-dynamical

It seems the Cassandra driver supports this: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1397
